# Камень ножницы бумага и колодец, помогите сделать сообщение типа Try again?, выбор ответа Yes (y) и No (n). y-перезагрузка кода, n-закрытие

Tags: python

```
import random
while True:
  pc=0
  user=0
  for i in range(3):
    print('Round',i+1)
    a=input('input: r(rock) p(paper) s(scissors) k')
    b=random.choice('rpsk')
    print(a)
    print(b)
    if a==b:
        print('Draw')
    if a=='r' and b=='s':
        print('U win!')
        user=user+1
    if a=='r' and b=='p':
        print('U lose')
        pc=pc+1
    if a=='s' and b=='p':
        print('U win!')
        user=user+1
    if a=='s' and b=='r':
        print('U lose!')
        pc=pc+1
    if a=='p' and b=='r':
        print('U win')
        user=user+1
    if a=='p' and b=='s':
        print('U lose')
        pc=pc+1
    if a=='p' and b=='k':
        print('U win')
        user=user+1
    if a=='r' and b=='k':
        print('U lose')
        pc=pc+1
    if a=='k' and b=='r':
        print('U win')
        user=user+1
    if a=='k' and b=='s':
        print('U win')
        user=user+1
    if a=='k' and b=='p':
        print('U lose')
        pc=pc+1
    if a=='s' and b=='k':
        print('U lose')
        pc=pc+1
   
if user>pc:
    print(f'U win! U win {user} ruands!')
    
        
else:
    print(f'U lose. U win {user} ruands.')
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот так только будет реагировать на y и на n. Основной код почти не трогал.

```
import random


def exit_app():
    exit = input('y or n = ')
    if exit == 'y':
        return True
    elif exit == 'n':
        return False
    else:
        return exit_app()


def app():
    pc = 0
    user = 0
    for i in range(3):
        print('Round',i+1)
        a=input('input: r(rock) p(paper) s(scissors) k')
        b=random.choice('rpsk')
        print(a)
        print(b)
        if a==b:
            print('Draw')
        if a=='r' and b=='s':
            print('U win!')
            user=user+1
        if a=='r' and b=='p':
            print('U lose')
            pc=pc+1
        if a=='s' and b=='p':
            print('U win!')
            user=user+1
        if a=='s' and b=='r':
            print('U lose!')
            pc=pc+1
        if a=='p' and b=='r':
            print('U win')
            user=user+1
        if a=='p' and b=='s':
            print('U lose')
            pc=pc+1
        if a=='p' and b=='k':
            print('U win')
            user=user+1
        if a=='r' and b=='k':
            print('U lose')
            pc=pc+1
        if a=='k' and b=='r':
            print('U win')
            user=user+1
        if a=='k' and b=='s':
            print('U win')
            user=user+1
        if a=='k' and b=='p':
            print('U lose')
            pc=pc+1
        if a=='s' and b=='k':
            print('U lose')
            pc=pc+1

        if user>pc:
            print(f'U win! U win {user} ruands!')
        else:
            print(f'U lose. U win {user} ruands.')
    exit = exit_app()
    if exit == True:
        return app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app()
```